# replacing a netcdf variable and rewrite to a new netcdf file

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

could anyone please help me with the following issue.
I have a netcdf file with the following dimensions and variables:
dimensions(sizes): y(100), n2(2), x(100),
variables(dimensions): int64 valid_time(), int64 start_time(), float64 y(y), float64 y_bounds(y,n2), float64 x(x), float64 x_bounds(x,n2), int16 precipitation(y,x), int8 proj()

The netcdf contains a 2d array (100,100) for percipitation. Now I have a new same size 2d array (100,100) with diffrent values. I was wondring how can replace the array inside the netcdf with the new one and rewrite it as a new netcdf. I tried the following code but it cant replace the array (it can just rewrite and rename the file.nc to newfile.nc without replacing the array)

```
import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
precip=ds.variables['precipitation']
precip=np.array(precip)
precip=new_array
ds.to_netcdf('newfile.nc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First provide your `new_array` as a 2D numpy array, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
new_array = np.array(new_array)
```

Then you can try:

```
import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
ds.variables['precipitation'].values = new_array
ds.to_netcdf('newfile.nc)
```

or

```
import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
ds['precipitation'].values = new_array
ds.to_netcdf('newfile.nc)
```

But just be careful that the x and y dimensions and the way your `new_array` is mapped onto the grid centers should be consistent with your `precipitation`.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy. Yes, I tried that, but it gives me this error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16556/2626514753.py in <module>
      1 ds=xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
----> 2 ds.variables['precipitation']=new_array
      3 ds.to_netcdf('newfile.nc') 

TypeError: 'Frozen' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Jab I have updated my answer after testing using my own netcdf file. It should work if the new array is a numpy 2D array. Yesterday I just gave an intuitive answer as I did something like this before, but got the wrong syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy. Now it works for me too. Really appriciate your time and consideration. Good time!

Comment: Hello @Jeremy. Could you please help me with an issue regarding the above question. I tried to assaing and replace two same size arrays (one for precipitation and the other one for time) with the array inside netcdf. For precipitation I could replace and write it, but for time it was not possible. This is a part of array for time; array([[220190701000000, 220190701000000, 220190701000000, ...,
        220190701000000, 220190701000000, 220190701000000],...]]). When I try to write the netcdf (ds.to_netcdf('newfile.nc)), it makes a netcdf that all values of the new array (for time) are zero.

Comment: @Jab Hi, I did a quick test, and I got values like "2.201907e+14" in the resulted netcdf file. I don't know what is causing your issue here, maybe you can try to change the time format?

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy for your time and consideration. Yes, the problem is with the dtype. The dtype of the precipitation in the netcdf file is float32, and I need to change it to float64. I'm really sorry for taking your time. Can you please let me know how I can change the dtype? I tried the following script and it didnt work.   ds.variables['precipitation'].values = np.float64(ds.variables['precipitation'].values)

Comment: @Jab I think ``ds.variables['precipitation'].values = ds.variables['precipitation'].values.astype('float64')`` should work